# Session values not stored in wicket application using Chrome

Tags: java, session, wicket

Our wicket application has the following scenario:

- save myValue in the session
- redirect the user to an external page
- the external pages redirects back to our webapp after the user entered some data
- read myValue from the session and do something based on myValue

It all works just fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Using Chrome myValue is null when the user returns to the our wicket page again. My first guess was that a new session must have been created or that myValue was never set. I debugged through the code and the session id is exactly the same ... myValue has also been set before the user got redirected.

I don't quite get how Chrome and Firefox would behave differently when it comes to saving values into the wicket session. Or how leaving the webpage and returning to it 1 minute later would suddenly result in a different kind of session.

Comment: update: it also works in Safari and IE .. Chrome is the only browser, it doesn't work in

Comment: Are the JSESSIONID cookie paths/data/etc all the same?

Comment: Can you post code that's reasonably small and has the problem?

Comment: One thing you could try to use Chrome from another machine, just to be sure the problem is not caused by some configuration in yours.

Comment: I ran into something similar on my production site.  Some bizarre combination of Chrome + Apache + mod_jk + Tomcat + Wicket was causing components to be dropped from the session, making it impossible to login to my app.  But only with Chrome...all other browsers worked great.  The solution?  Adding a favicon.ico.  I kid you not.  Definitely a bug in Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

The use-case that you have mentioned your site --> external site  --> your site is something I have encountered when I was working on OAUTH authentication where the flow is same i.e my site --> facebook  -->my site.

My solution was not to rely upon browser session/cookie; I persisted all the  data I needed to reload the session and sent the user to FB along with a key (used to identify the cached session information )and also had FB pass back this key to my application which I then used to reload the session data.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely floored because the favicon solution mentioned above worked for me.  Been pulling hair for 3 years on this and can't believe the fix is so simple.  I reported this fix to Chrome.

I'm front ending Tomcat 6.0.32 with Apache 2.2.14 in ContOS 5.7.  Tomcat is hosting a Java Struts application.  Simply added

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/festival/images/ft_ico_2.ico"/>
```

in all the `head` tags for each and every jsp page.  Problem solved !!